# Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.NameAccessAllowed always returns False on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to retrieve the user name of the user who is running the application on the windows phone.

```
      if (UserInformation.NameAccessAllowed == true)
        {
            MSG.Append("" + await UserInformation.GetFirstNameAsync());
            MSG.Append(" " + await UserInformation.GetLastNameAsync());
        }
```

It always return false. I am using my account which does have a first and last name on a device. So it should work. Are there any secret settings to add to the application manifest or does this just not work on the phone.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: No I do not have an answer to this one

Comment: same problem. did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I have not found a solution to  this one